# How to count concurrently bookings in sql in time interval per minute?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, count, recursive-query

If I have a start and stop time for a booking, how can I calculate the number of bookings there are each minute? I made a simplified version of my database table looks like here:

```
Start time        | End time         | booking   |
--------------------------------------------------
2020-09-01 10:00  | 2020-09-01 10:10 | Booking 1 |
2020-09-01 10:00  | 2020-09-01 10:05 | Booking 2 |
2020-09-01 10:05  | 2020-09-01 10:10 | Booking 3 |
2020-09-01 10:09  | 2020-09-01 10:10 | Booking 4 |
```

I want to have the bookings between a given time interval like 10:02 - 10:09. It should be something like this as result:

### Desired result

```
Time  | count
-----------
10:02 | 2 |
10:03 | 2 |
10:04 | 2 |
10:05 | 3 |
10:06 | 2 |
10:07 | 2 |
10:08 | 2 |
10:09 | 3 |
```

### Question

How can this be achieved? Today I export it to python however I think it should be possible to achieve directly in SQL.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? And see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE directly on your data:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select start_time, end_time
      from t
      union all
      select start_time + interval 1 minute, end_time
      from cte
      where start_time < end_time
     )
select start_time, count(*)
from cte
group by start_time
order by start_time;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=75424d47c4439423b8f6b2e51e75a36e) is a db<>fiddle.

EDIT:

In earlier versions of MySQL, it helps to have a tally table. You can create one on the fly, using something like:

```
(select @rn := @rn + 1 as n
 from t cross join
      (select @rn := 0) params
) tally
```

You need enough numbers for your maximum span, but then you can do:

```
select t.start_time + interval tally.n hour, count(*)
from t join
     (select @rn := @rn + 1 as n
      from t cross join
           (select @rn := -1) params  -- so it starts from 0
      limit 100
     ) tally
     on t.start_time + interval tally.n hour <= t.end_time
group by t.start_time + interval tally.n hour;
```

Comment: thanks, is it possible to make this work also for mysql 5.7?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive query to generate the timestamp range, then unpivot the table and join:

```
with recursive dates (ts) as(
    select '2020-09-01'
    union all
    select ts + interval 1 minute 
    from dates 
    where ts + itnerval 1 minute < '2020-09-02'
)
select d.ts, sum(t.cnt) over(order by d.ts) cnt
from dates d
left join (
    select start_time ts, 1 cnt from mytable
    union all select end_time, -1 from mytable
) t on t.ts <= d.ts
```

If you are going to run this repeatedly and/or against large time periods, you would better materialize the date ranges in a calendar table rather than use a recursive query. The calendar table has one row per minute over a large period of dates - assuming a table called `date_calendar`, you would do:

```
select d.ts, sum(t.cnt) over(order by d.ts) cnt
from date_calendar d
left join (
    select start_time ts, 1 cnt from mytable
    union all select end_time, -1 from mytable
) t on t.ts <= d.ts
where d.ts >= '2020-09-01' and d.ts < '2020-09-02'
```