# How to count concurrently bookings in sql in time interval per minute by booking type?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, count, recursive-query

I have created a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3fcf1afd3ae930adcb7f6dd1f4128afe):

If I have this table of bookings (I have simplified here to make it easier to test, it should be much longer and have different booking names):

```
+---------------------+---------------------+---------+
|      tart_time      |      end_time       | booking |
+---------------------+---------------------+---------+
| 2020-09-01 10:00:00 | 2020-09-01 10:10:00 | Tesla   |
| 2020-09-01 10:00:00 | 2020-09-01 10:10:00 | Tesla   |
| 2020-09-01 10:00:00 | 2020-09-01 10:05:00 | Volvo   |
| 2020-09-01 10:05:00 | 2020-09-01 10:10:00 | Tesla   |
| 2020-09-01 10:05:00 | 2020-09-01 10:10:00 | Volvo   |
| 2020-09-01 10:09:00 | 2020-09-01 10:10:00 | Tesla   |
+---------------------+---------------------+---------+
```

I want to create an SQL query that create this table:

```
+---------------------+-------+-------+-------+---------+
|     start_time      | total | Tesla | Volvo | Brand_X |
+---------------------+-------+-------+-------+---------+
| 2020-09-01 10:00:00 |     3 |     2 |     1 | X       |
| 2020-09-01 10:01:00 |     3 |     2 |     1 | X       |
| 2020-09-01 10:02:00 |     3 |     2 |     1 | X       |
| 2020-09-01 10:03:00 |     3 |     2 |     1 | X       |
| 2020-09-01 10:04:00 |     3 |     2 |     1 | X       |
| 2020-09-01 10:05:00 |     5 |     3 |     2 | X       |
| 2020-09-01 10:06:00 |     4 |     3 |     1 | X       |
| 2020-09-01 10:07:00 |     4 |     3 |     1 | X       |
| 2020-09-01 10:08:00 |     4 |     3 |     1 | X       |
| 2020-09-01 10:09:00 |     5 |     4 |     1 | X       |
| 2020-09-01 10:10:00 |     5 |     4 |     1 | X       |
+---------------------+-------+-------+-------+---------+
```

I got some help before here:
[How to count concurrently bookings in sql in time interval per minute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63713227/how-to-count-concurrently-bookings-in-sql-in-time-interval-per-minute)

This is my current solution:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select start_time, end_time, booking
      from t
      union all
      select start_time + interval 1 minute, end_time, booking
      from cte
      where start_time < end_time
     ),
     booking_typs as (
     select distinct booking
     from t
     )
select 
    start_time, 
    count(*) as total, 
    count(if(cte.booking = 'Tesla', cte.booking, NULL)) as Tesla,
    count(if(cte.booking = 'Volvo', cte.booking, NULL)) as Volvo
from cte
group by start_time
order by start_time
```

However I should like to have it more dynamic so it can generate more columns on the fly, not to be hard coded. I started to get different booking_typs in its own table but I don´t have any idea how to include them in the select. I can do this part in code, but should like to do it directly in SQL.

**My questions:**

- How to add dynamically the columns for booking_typs?
- I should like to have a solution for both MySQL 5.7 and MySQL 8.0 (it don´t have to be same solution)?

Comment: To generate a variable number of columns, you need dynamic SQL, which is much more complicated.