# SQL Server Concurrent Events Per Minute

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I have a dataset that includes a set of events that happen at various times.

I need a mechanism to count concurrent events, by minute, including intervals with 0. The event names are irrelevant for this exercise - only the total of events active in an interval.

I have no control over the schema.

I initially tried some other subquery mechanisms but they are not performant on the amount of data I am dealing with.

In looking for solutions I did find a MySQL post that appears similar in nature to what I'm doing but I'm not able to successfully convert from the MySQL version of CTE over to SQL Server CTE.

MySQL Post for reference: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63713227/how-to-count-concurrently-bookings-in-sql-in-time-interval-per-minute)

I have a SQL Fiddle here that shows my latest attempts: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/fbbda5/1)

The fiddle shows the representative schema and data and the two versions that I've gotten closest with so far.

The commented version is a non-starter because it is EXTREMELY slow and the number of records in the table is very large (21 minutes to execute on my dataset). The CTE version doesn't get me there either because I can't seem to get the DateTime to behave recursively like it does on the MySQL side.

Ultimately what I am looking to produce is an output similar to:

```
DateTime  | count
-----------
[...records from midnight... that all show zero]
01/01/2021 10:00 | 1 |
[..records that all show 1]
01/01/2021 10:59 | 1 |
01/01/2021 11:00 | 2 |
[...more minutes @ count 2]
01/01/2021 12:29 | 2 |
01/01/2021 12:30 | 3 |
[and so on]
```

Any of you SQL Server wizards able to sort out what I need to do in order to get the results I'm looking for?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

**It looks like you need a `Minutes` table to start with, then join the other table to it and group.**

You can use a real table for this. I will manufacture one on the fly, using Itzik Ben-Gan's tally function:

```sql
-- calculate the total number of minutes
DECLARE @earliest datetime = '20210101 10:00:00';
DECLARE @latest datetime = '20210101 22:00:00';
DECLARE @totalminutes int = DATEDIFF(minute, @earliest, @latest) + 1;

WITH
    L0 AS ( SELECT 1 AS c 
            FROM (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),
                        (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS D(c) ),
    L1 AS ( SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 AS A CROSS JOIN L0 AS B ),
    L2 AS ( SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 AS A CROSS JOIN L1 AS B ),
    L3 AS ( SELECT 1 AS c FROM L2 AS A CROSS JOIN L2 AS B ),
    Nums AS ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rownum
              FROM L3 ),
    Minutes AS (
        SELECT TOP (@totalminutes)
           DATEADD(minute, rownum - 1, @earliest) AS startMin,
           DATEADD(minute, rownum    , @earliest) AS endMin
        FROM Nums
    )
select m.startMin, count(*)
from Minutes m
JOIN test t ON t.CurrentDateTime < m.endMin AND t.OriginalDateTime >= m.startMin
GROUP BY m.startMin
ORDER BY m.startMin;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/fbbda5/12)

You need to adjust the maximum number of rows, as well as the number of cross-joins, in order to manufacture the right amount of rows in `Minutes`.

If you want minutes which don't have any results at all, change `JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: This works as a solution but takes a LONG time to run on a very large dataset (several million records) - it does run though and achieves the results I was looking for so appreciate the assist there!

Comment: A real `Minutes` table properly indexed, may help you